# How does the "main" controller access $routeParams in this example?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, model-view-controller

I'm experimenting with `$routeParams`, by following along with [this example](http://plnkr.co/edit/ngdoc%3aexample-%24route-service@snapshot?p=preview) in the AngularJS documentation. For reference, here is the script itself:

```
 angular.module('ngRouteExample', ['ngRoute'])

   .controller('MainController', function($scope, $route, $routeParams, $location) {
       $scope.$route = $route;
       $scope.$location = $location;
       $scope.$routeParams = $routeParams;
   })

   .controller('BookController', function($scope, $routeParams) {
       $scope.name = "BookController";
       $scope.params = $routeParams;
   })

   .controller('ChapterController', function($scope, $routeParams) {
       $scope.name = "ChapterController";
       $scope.params = $routeParams;
   })

  .config(function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $routeProvider
     .when('/Book/:bookId', {
      templateUrl: 'book.html',
      controller: 'BookController',
      resolve: {
        // I will cause a 1 second delay
        delay: function($q, $timeout) {
          var delay = $q.defer();
          $timeout(delay.resolve, 1000);
          return delay.promise;
        }
      }
    })
    .when('/Book/:bookId/ch/:chapterId', {
      templateUrl: 'chapter.html',
      controller: 'ChapterController'
    });

    // configure html5 to get links working on jsfiddle
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  });
```

What I can't understand is this: **how does `MainController` get the updated `$routeParam` object?** I can see that as I click, items that `MainController` is responsible for setting are changing, but I don't understand *how*. It's making it a little tough to reproduce this behavior.

Comment: I think AngularJS is creating a new instance of the MainController when the route changes but I'm not 100% sure so I'm not going to put that as an answer.

Comment: That's what has me so stumped--it must be getting re-instantiated, but I don't know how. :-(

Comment: Perhaps all controllers are re-instantiated when the route changes. Controllers aren't long lived objects.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't get re-instantiated, and it's not "getting" the updated `$routeParams` object - the object in the controller is *the* `routeParams` object.  It is the *same* object that is in the other controllers, not a "copy" of it.

So when the $routeParams object gets changed, the other controller *already has the changes.*

Comment: This was the kickstart to my brain that I needed. It's a reference back to `$routeParams`.